# Pass in javascript param in URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to back end this and maybe get lucky modifying the url, what happens is there is javascript code that loads specific data and I want to be able to pass in the script via the URL.  Is this possible and how would i do it?

For example here is the javascript: `javascript:ChangeEvsVol('1035','3')`
here is the urL:`https:///app/template/simple%2CDownloadQuotasScreen.vm`

Is there a way to manipulate the URL to use that param?  I throw in into Firebug command console and it grabs exactly what I need.

Comment: eh? Maybe you want to make your question clearer.

Comment: I need to be able to load those specific variables directly into the URL that's plugged into the browser

Answer (score -1):

```
document.location ="mysite.php?var1=" + JSvar1 +"&var2=" + JSvar2
```

Comment: is document.location javascript?

Comment: It should be `window.location`, not `document.location`.

Comment: Mike: It's just an EXAMPLE. Adjust to your own needs.